# Error VS800075 in Delivery Plans (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure-devops

we have created a new plan in „Delivery plans”. The plan includes information from various projects. Unfortunately, some people (with Basic access level) have an error message when trying to open the plan: Failed to load data with following error:
"VS800075: The project with id 'vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/b834eb3e-9822-4975-8c72-6404f78e0e37' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it."

A project with the given ID exists, users can access and edit it. Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Are the answers helpful to you? Please check the answer. And if you have any question,we are willing to help you.

Answer (score 2):

We found the issue. The people that can’t view the Delivery plan don’t have access to the various projects.